# Data Buffer Exceeded error while connecting BW Cube

Tags: r

I am reading data from BW Cube with the following code

actual <- RSAPReadCube(conn, 'ZAPO_C17', chars=list('ZBEGINV', 'ZKF339', 'ZTOTJFF', 'ZOPENPL6', 'ZDLV_QTY', 'ZBACKLOG2'), kfigures=list('ZBEGINV', 'ZKF339', 'ZTOTJFF', 'ZOPENPL6', 'ZDLV_QTY', 'ZBACKLOG2'))

I am getting following error:
**Error: Problem Invoking RFC (RSDPL_CUBE_DATA_READ): 5 / INHERITED_ERROR / ID:RS_EXCEPTION Type:E Number:000 Subfield access (offset = 0, length = 1-) to adata object of size 30 outside valid limits**

Please help

Comment: Which software did you use? How big is the file/connection (what type of data is this?) ? What is your sessionInfo? Could you post an example that reproduce this problem?

Comment: Hi, I am using R

Comment: It is historical data

Comment: There isn't enough information here for us to help you. I don't know what you're connecting to or what your environment is like. Maybe your data is larger than the memory available? Have you tried using a smaller data set?

Comment: I am connecting SAP BIW and retrieving data

Comment: I have previously, connected with DataMart and was able to retrieve 7gb of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with correct argument - which has Characteristic Technical Name

actual <- RSAPReadCube(conn, 'ZAPO_C17', chars=list('0MATERIAL', 'ZBWSDVERS'), kfigures=list('ZBEGINV', 'ZKF339', 'ZTOTJFF', 'ZOPENPL6', 'ZDLV_QTY', 'ZBACKLOG2'))